# Parsing multipart form data on the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Suppose I have a form for uploading a file:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
<% end %>
```

I need to parse the multipart data of that file manually on the server in an action, in particular I need to get its length and name:

```
def upload
  # ???
end
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file will be a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object, which is similar to a `Tempfile` object.

```
def upload
  picture = params[:picture]
  size = picture.size
  filename = picture.original_filename
  # do some stuff with the file
end
```

You can read more about file uploads in the Rails documentation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

Comment: doesn't really answer the question